# Vertical alignment of text and progress bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, vertical-alignment

This might be simple but I am not able to align a text and a progress bar. It seems the text is based on baseline and the progress bar renders from the top. How can I align the three elements vertically central?

In html,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4"> sample-1 </div>
   <div> class="col-xs-4 progress>
       <div class="progress-bar" data-progress="80"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4"> x </div>
```

In css,

```
.col-xs-4 { width: 33.33333%; float: left; line-height: 24px;}
.progress { height: auto;}
.progress-bar { float: left; height: 18px;}
```

The outcome is all elements sit on the baseline. [image]

I want to align the text and close mark  vertically central with the progress bar.

Comment: I changed the progress bar height to the line-height, it worked. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going for is, css - `position:relative; text-align:center;` no `float` and no `width`. Also, I don't know if it's like that in your code, but this `<div> class="col-xs-4 progress>` looks a little funky.